# Triclops SDK Function Breaks ros::NodeHandle

Tags: ros, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have a problem incorporating Point Grey Research's Triclops SDK into ROS. I've created a simple test ROS package that illustrates this problem based on the simple C++ publisher shown in the following tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B). Here is the code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "triclops.h"

#include <sstream>

/**
 * Function to handle error checking for the Triclops SDK
 */
void triclopsErrorHandler(const char* function_name, TriclopsError te) {
    if(te != TriclopsErrorOk) {
            std::cout << "TRICLOPS_ERROR: " << function_name << " reported " << triclopsErrorToString(te) << "." << std::endl;
            exit(1);
    }
}

/**
 * This tutorial demonstrates simple sending of messages over the ROS system.
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

  int count = 0;
  TriclopsContext shortContext;
  TriclopsError te;
  // THE FOLLOWING LINE BREAKS ROS UNLESS IT'S COMMENTED OUT
  te = triclopsGetDefaultContextFromFile(&shortContext, "../short.cal");
  triclopsErrorHandler("triclopsGetDefaultContextFromFile", te);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    std_msgs::String msg;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "hello world " << count;
    msg.data = ss.str();

    ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());

    chatter_pub.publish(msg);

    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ++count;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Whenever the following line:

> te = triclopsGetDefaultContextFromFile(&shortContext, "../short.cal");

is NOT commented, I get the following segfault in gdb:

```
$ gdb ./bin/testTriclops 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/andrew-am3p/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/testTriclops/bin/testTriclops...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/andrew-am3p/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/testTriclops/bin/testTriclops 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
testTriclops: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) -         __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)    ((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) &&     ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7b5f1df in raise () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb7b62825 in abort () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb7ba6469 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0xb7ba9293 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0xb7baadec in malloc () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0xb7deb627 in operator new(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0xb7f92124 in ros::initInternalTimerManager() () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#8  0xb7f74e65 in ros::start() () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#9  0xb7f4a707 in ros::NodeHandle::construct(std::string const&, bool) () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#10 0xb7f4b893 in ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::string const&, std::map<std::string, std::string,             std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&) ()
from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#11 0x0806bc40 in main (argc=28, argv=0x0) at /home/andrew-        am3p/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/testTriclops/src/testTriclops.cpp:39
```

When that line is commented out, the software runs perfectly fine. Any ideas on how to eliminate this problem? Thanks in advance for any help! Below is the CMakeLists.txt I use to build this package with rosmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

link_libraries(triclops pnmutils)
rosbuild_add_executable(testTriclops src/testTriclops.cpp)
```

Please note, for some reason the "<<" operator is being replaced with & l t ; & l t ; in the code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124716/triclops-sdk-function-breaks-ros::nodehandle/) by [Andrew Capodieci](https://answers.ros.org/users/5136/andrew-capodieci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2014-01-30**:
I seem to recall this is because PointGrey statically links in some libraries that ROS also uses, and you get all sorts of bizarre symbol conflicts.  It's been a while since I have looked at this, though.

**Comment by [Andrew Capodieci](https://answers.ros.org/users/5136/andrew-capodieci/) on 2014-01-30**:
the point grey triclops library is a static library (triclops.a) so this makes sense...in the cmake I had to put link_libraries(triclops) so that the triclops libraries were linked first and so ROS didn't depend on it. Would this have prevented the issue you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks more like a memory corruption bug than anything specifically related to ROS. Note that the stacktrace shows that it's failing somewhere inside of malloc().

My best guess is that the call to `triclopsGetDefaultContextFromFile` is corrupting memory or the memory allocator in some way; either the call itself or the arguments that you're passing to it.

A tool like valgrind may be able to help spot memory corruption issues earlier.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew Capodieci](https://answers.ros.org/users/5136/andrew-capodieci/) on 2014-01-30**:
I don't believe this is the problem because I have a standalone C++ library that uses the same function without ROS and it works. The problem only arises when I try to port my standalone C++ library into a ros package.

**Comment by [Andrew Capodieci](https://answers.ros.org/users/5136/andrew-capodieci/) on 2014-01-30**:
Also isn't the code never getting to call triclopsGetDefaultContextFromFile because the segfault occurs in the construction of the NodeHandle, which is the 2nd line of code?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-30**:
It's hard to tell where the NodeHandle creation that's triggering the error is happening, because the line numbers reported by GDB don't match up with the code sample that you've posted.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-30**:
I'm still going to recommend running your node in valgrind to see if it can find any bad memory accesses.

**Comment by [Andrew Capodieci](https://answers.ros.org/users/5136/andrew-capodieci/) on 2014-01-30**:
I think I copy and pasted the gdb run from when I had comments in the code. I ran it again and it occurs on line 24, which corresponds to the ros::NodeHandle n; line in the sample code. I'll try valgrind just in case and let you know tomorrow what I get for an output.

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2015-06-25**:
I can confirm the bug that is very alike. I do not even call any function from the point grey code. Moreover, I don't even include their stuff. The memory corruption occurs right after linking. So a single change in CMake causes the bug. If I do not link against it - I run everything ok